# Google Sheets - Script: Import CSV with less than 30000 cells, returns Exception: ...above the 5000000 cell limit?

Tags: google-sheets, csv-import

I have a CSV file with less than 1200 rows (will grow in the future) and 22 columns (maybe more or less, later), that I'm trying to import into a Google Sheet by this script

```
function importCSV() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Although a quick calculation shows that the data does not exceed 30,000 cells, it returns the error:

> Exception: This action will increase the number of cells in the
> workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.

Someone who can give me a hand with this? =(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the solution by myself. Just deleting any extra/blank column beyond "Z" (26)... which is quite a bit, more than I need for now.

Googling, I have read that Google counts all cells (existing and to exist) at the time of executing the import script, so the total number of cells would be given by all the blank cells in the sheet... plus the cells to be inserted when importing the data.

Reducing the number of blank cells in the target sheet seems to solve the problem =)